# How to convert datetime in c# so it works with sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime-format

If i write the following query in sql it works fine, but if i run it from my c# program it fails.  I get a -1 value as the result of the query.  I think it has something to do with the conversion. It supposed to be a third textbox in the program and in it the result of the query (the result should be displayed in the third textbox). Here is the code:

```
 conn.Open();
            string anfrage = "select sum(Rechnungsbetrag)  from tbl_Rechnung where AusDatum between '"+txtbox1.Text+"' and '"+txtbox2.Text+"'"; 
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(anfrage, conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: "it fails" - meaning what?

Comment: i get a -1 value as the result of the query

Comment: try something else... write in `txtbox1`: `2014-01-01` and in `txtbox2`: `2014-01-01'; truncate table tbl_Rechnung; --` ;)

Comment: @balexandre: That is VERY mean!

Comment: @balexandre Sigh. You consider this funny, don't you? "Jokes" like this (*run `rm -rf /`, and all your problems will go away*) have never been funny, are not funny and will never be. At best, they are superfluous - at worst, someone *will* run this - do you want to responsible for someone losing their data?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt learning the hard way, we never forget ;)

Answer (score 1):

Format your date in ISO8601 format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn[ Z ]

Here's how you do this in C#: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip)

Comment: Haven't TS to take care about SQL Server [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of  things wrong.  First, txtbox1.text and txtbox2.text are strings.  You have to convert them to DateTime objects.

Next, you really want to use query parameters for a variety of reasons.

Finally, with date range queries, the between keyword can cause you to miss records.  It's safer to do this sort of thing:

```
where SomeDateField >= @StartDate
and SomeDateField < the day after @EndDate
```

Comment: i want to pull from the sql table sum (money) of all sales depending on the 2 dates (from, to) i write in the textboxes.When i try to convert them to datetime i get -1 as the result. But in the sql when you write the same query you write your dates as a string, that´s why i dont understand why is it not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string anfrage = "select sum(Rechnungsbetrag)  from tbl_Rechnung where AusDatum between Convert(varchar(10),'"+txtbox1.Text+"',102) and Convert(varchar(10),'"+txtbox2.Text+"',102)";
```